# How to save levelplot() with like cells merged

Tags: r, graphics, spatial, heatmap, levelplot

Say I have a heatmap with contours like so:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(runif(100*200),nrow=100)
X <- apply(X,1,sort)
#png("Surface.png",width=800,height=400)
lattice::levelplot(t(X),contour=TRUE)
#dev.off()
getwd()
```

it looks like this:
[image: An example contour/surface plot]

There are many ways to make variants of this in R (`fields::image.plot()`, `image()`, and so forth. If I save this filled contour plot as a pdf, it's a squeaky-clean vector image that I can rescale and include in a conference poster (using e.g., Inkscape). It turns out in this case that the like-colored areas are actually individual raster cells rather than merged polygons implying a very large number of vertices, which hogs memory and slows down Inkscape after including a couple such surfaces in the poster. The easiest solution would be so save out to the ideal merged-cell format from R, where the contiguous like-colored areas are unified/merged `polygon()`s or similar, thereby decreasing the number of vertices by an order of magnitude or more.

My question is whether there is some surface function that already does this by default, or a low effort way to emulate this kind of surface output. The high-effort approach would be to dive into R's spatial functions to merge like cells, but I'd rather avoid this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it make a difference adding `panel = panel.levelplot.raster` inside `levelplot`?

Comment: @Pascal Unfortunately no. If I save it out to pdf using the raster option then I still get a large number of small square cells, so this won't cut it. Thanks, though

Comment: I was afraid of that. There was a [discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Creating-smooth-color-regions-with-panel-contourplot-td866253.html) on that topic several years ago, if it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "high-effort approach" (not really)

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(runif(100*200),nrow=100)
X <- apply(X,1,sort)
lattice::levelplot(X,contour=TRUE)

library(raster)
r <- raster(X)
z <- cut(r, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
p <- rasterToPolygons(z, dissolve=TRUE)
spplot(p)
```